# Java multiple inheritance particular issue

Tags: java

I have the following situation:

I need my class let's say `A` to extend `JComponent` and a different class let's say `B`.

Now, I know that multiple inheritance is not possible in java, and that a proper way to do this would be to implement `BInterface` which will give me access to all methods from `B`.

The issue is that class `B` contains ~15 methods, and inside `A` I only need to override 2 of them, and all the other ones to use the 'super' implementation.

Question is: is there a possible way to do this without having to implement inside `A` all the methods from `B`?

Note: I'm not trying to add too much complexity to my code, if the 'workaround' for this problem breaks oop programming principles then I should better redesign my code.

Comment: you could add default implementation to the interface methods so you don't have to implement all of them in the A class.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/java-static-default-methods

Comment: If `A` only needs 2 members out of `B`, those two members should probably exist in their own type, so clients won't have to rely on the entirety of `B` just to access the few dependencies they need. Segregate the interface.

Answer (score 2):

As you said multiple inheritance is not supported in java. But in general its a good practice to use composition instead of inheritance [[Effective Java - item 18]](https://dev.to/kylec32/effective-java-tuesday-favor-composition-over-inheritance-4ph5). Read about it [here](http://web.mit.edu/6.005/www/fa14/classes/14-inheritance/)

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0134685997

Answer (score 0):

**You can use default implementation of java 8 feature.**

1. Create an interface named as **ABinterface**. provide all 13 methods as default means 
   having definition and declare 2 methods (like abstract methods).
2. Class A and B will implement **ABinterface** and override those 2 methods according to 
   their need.
3. Class A which will extend **jsComponent** and implement **ABInterface** can access all 
   other existing 13 methods also.

   You haven't provided the enough information in this query. So you need to think according 
   to real word scenarios with oops concepts before implementing this.

   **You can also use composition instead of inheritance.**